# Very basic MySQL query returning zero rows after upgrading from 5.1 to 5.6 and switching to InnoDB from MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

We've very recently updated MySQL to version 5.6 from 5.1 (and previously 5.0) and at the same time changed from MyISAM to InnoDB. Although the majority of our application is working without issue, we're seeing some very strange results. The following example query returns zero rows:

```
SELECT * FROM product_data WHERE product_cond='N' AND product_live='M'
```

Removing either part of the WHERE clause returns results as expected, however there are 1000's of rows that match the full criteria.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or any idea why we're seeing this?

Comment: When you converted, maybe you also changed the collation from case-insensitive to case-sensitive?

Comment: Can you show the output of `show create table product_data` in the two versions of the database?

Comment: This won't answer the question at hand, but might be worth checking for other conversion issues:  [MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).